# IOS: app in background show splash

Tags: ios, background

I have a strange problem in my app; 
Sometime and not everytime, when I put my app in background and I resume it after a long time it restart from splash and after it, the app restart from firstviewcontroller; but if I put app in background and I resume it quickly it don't happen, why?

Comment: What version of iOS? Before 6.0, your views were automatically freed on low memory warnings.

Comment: it happens in iOS 6 and iOS 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put your app in the background, iOS reserves the right to terminate it when system memory pressure gets to high.  When you leave for a long time, you are actually seeing the app restart.  When you leave for a short time you haven't had time to encounter a low memory condition and the app resumes where it left off.

From [Apple's App States and Multitasking Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html), emphasis added:

> **Suspended**: The app is in the background but is not executing code. The system moves apps to this state automatically and does not notify them before doing so. While suspended, an app remains in memory but does not execute any code.
>   **When a low-memory condition occurs, the system may purge suspended apps without notice to make more space for the foreground app.**

Comment: Is ARC that do that? Is there a way to disable this memory management for my app?

Comment: This is system wide, nothing to do with ARC. Any background app can be terminated with few exceptions.  Apps that are playing music (like Pandora) or actively polling position (like Nike+) won't get terminated.

Comment: and can I disable this thing?

Comment: Nope. You could plan for it like some apps do, save the current state on `applicationWillTerminate:` and restoring it when the app launches.